# Sql - Getting the row quantity and selecting a certain row id and get the following rows

Tags: php, mysql, sql, sql-server

Say I have a table `chattable`

```
  id           sender           touser         message
----------------------------------------------------
1            User1            User2           Hi
2            User2            User1           Hello
3            User3            User1           How r u
4            User1            User3           r u there?
5            User1            User2           Hey
```

I'd like to do the following

1) Get the quantity of rows with same values.

For example- I want to select from `chattable` the quantity  of rows that have User1 as the sender and User2 as the touser. In this example, that would be 2.

I understand that in order to select those rows I should choose the next line of code -

```
SELECT sender, touser FROM chattable WHERE sender=User1, touser=User2;
```

But how can i get the quantity of rows that contain this info?

2) The other thing I'm trying to understand is how can get rows data from a certain row and also form following rows with the same value.

Meaning, I want to use the next code - to get the max value of row id -

```
SELECT sender, touser FROM chattable WHERE sender=User1, touser=User2, id=( SELECT max(id) FROM chattable );
```

What should I chamge it in order to get the max id number - in my example it should be row id 5 , not because it's the last row in the whole table, just because it's the last row with the value of User1 as sender and User2 as touser.

So let's say now I've got the max id value which is 5.

Now let's say the table got new rows in it -

```
  id           sender           touser         message
----------------------------------------------------
6            User3            User2           Hi There
7            User1            User2           Hi There
8            User1            User2           Hello to u 2
9            User3            User1           How r u
```

Now I would like to know if there's a new rows with the same conditions - User1 as sender and User2 as touser.

So let's say I'm getting the new max id value - which is now 8.

But i want to get not only the info from row 8 but also from 7 as well.

So what should be the sql line in order to get all the rows that are bigger than row 5 but also having the conditions of User1 as sender and User2 as touser.

Hope I've made my question clear - and thanks for any kind of help

Comment: could you provide the result data that you desire for 2nd question?

Comment: I would like to get all the data from rows 7 and 8 - because let's say i've got rows 1 and5 data already. I would like to get all the data - id, sender, to user and message

Comment: One way i thought to do it - is if let's i've got the id of the last row - let say 5 - so i pass the 5 and tell it to give me the results between 5 and the max value - but i don't know how to do so

Comment: you can try select... from... where sender='User1' and touser='User2' and id > 5

Comment: Uh, why are both [mysql](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/mysql) and [sql-server](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/sql-server) listed as tags?

Answer (score 1):

For the first question you can have the number of rows with count:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM chattable WHERE sender=User1, touser=User2;
```

For the second point:

```
SELECT MAX(Id) AS HighestID FROM chattable WHERE sender=User1, touser=User2;
```

Answer (score 0):

You get total rows as this

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM chattable WHERE sender="User1" AND touser="User2";
```

For another question

```
SELECT id, sender, touser FROM chattable WHERE sender="User1" AND touser="User2" ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 1;
```

Answer (score 0):

1)

```
SELECT sender, touser, count(*) 
FROM chattable 
WHERE sender=User1, touser=User2;
```

2)

```
SELECT sender, touser, max(id) as latest_id 
FROM chattable 
WHERE sender=User1, touser=User2
```

Comment: I'm trying to understand the second solution - max(id) - should I declared it as equal to let's say 8, ot is it know to find it when I'm using max(id)? And what's the meaning of latest_id? I'm trying to understand how it knows to get the rows with the ids 7 and 8

Comment: It scans all ids where sender=User1 and touser=User2 and choose maximum (latest). I addded a name to the max found. It's just result column name nothing more

Comment: So how does he knows to get rows id number 7 and 8 - and not to get rows id 1 and 5. Still from what i understand it will only get row id 8 and not getting 7. How does it know to pick rows 8 and 7 and not 1 and 5?

Comment: Wouldn’t you need a `GROUP BY` to be allowed to use `MAX(id)` like that?

Answer (score -2):

1) You can use COUNT(*)

e.g.

```
SELECT count(*) FROM chattable WHERE sender=User1, touser=User2;
```

2) You could do it this way, using limit:

```
SELECT id, sender, touser, message FROM chattable WHERE sender=User1, touser=User2 ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 1
```

Or this way, using MAX() (which should be faster)

```
SELECT MAX(id), sender, touser, message FROM chattable WHERE sender=User1, touser=User2
```

Comment: +1 for the corrected. I think finding MAX() is faster than sort though

Comment: I would tend to agree. MAX() is ANSI compatible, and should work elsewhere, and LIMIT is to MySQL as TOP is to MSSQL. I'll add both :)

Comment: About the second solution - I don't understand how it knows how to get rows 7 and 8, and how it knows to ignore rows 1 and 5?

Comment: @4this The MAX() function returns the largest value of the selected column, you're identifying you only want data between sender and touser in the where clause - it is then picking the highest value

Comment: So it will get only the data from row id 8?

Comment: @4this I see what you mean - I missed that part. Personally, I would introduce an 'unread' flag instead (as that appears as though what he's trying to do) - would you agree?

Comment: Though [sql-server](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/sql-server) is in the question’s tags…